# Changes in 1 object property of observableArray changes same property of another object in same observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

If a property in one object is changed, the same property in another object gets updated in the same `observableArray`.

From UI: If I click Change Address button on every accordion, it's calling `populateSelectedAppoinment` function and in this I can get current updated data in `currentData`.

When I am assigning the values from `currentData` which are observables, to the first object of `observableArray`, while iterating over the same `observableArray`, same properties in a second object get modified with the same values. Which shouldn't happen.

```
{
  populateSelectedAppoinment: function(currentData) {

    var newShipmentDeliveryAddr = this.viewModel.observables.shipmentAddrArray();
    var currentOrderAction = sessionStorage.getItem('currentOrderAction');
    this.viewModel.observables.shipmentAddrArray([]);

    var that = this;
    _.each(newShipmentDeliveryAddr, function (shipAddr) {

      if (shipAddr && shipAddr.serviceIDX9 && (shipAddr.serviceIDX9 === currentData.serviceIDX9)) {
        shipAddr.selectedAppoinmentX9 = currentData.selectedSlotValue;
        shipAddr.deliveryInstructionsX9 = currentData.deliveryInstructions;
      }

      if (shipAddr && shipAddr.serviceIDX9 && currentOrderAction && (shipAddr.serviceIDX9 === currentOrderAction)) {

        shipAddr.shipingDetailsX9.customerAddressAddressBuildingValue = currentData.customerAddressAddressBuildingValue() === undefined ? '' : currentData.customerAddressAddressBuildingValue();
        shipAddr.shipingDetailsX9.customerAddressBuildingClassValue = currentData.customerAddressBuildingClassValue() === undefined ? '' : currentData.customerAddressBuildingClassValue();

        var customerAddressBuildingValue = shipAddr.shipingDetailsX9.customerAddressAddressBuildingValue;
        var customerAddressBuildingClassValue = shipAddr.shipingDetailsX9.customerAddressBuildingClassValue;

        shipAddr.shipingDetailsX9.deliveryAddressX9 = customerAddressBuildingValue + customerAddressBuildingClassValue;
        sessionStorage.setItem('currentOrderAction', null);
      }
      that.viewModel.observables.shipmentAddrArray.push(shipAddr);
    });
  }
}
```

EX:

I am expecting the below result when I do changes in object 0 and after iteration completes over the whole `observableArray`,

```
0:serviceID:'1234',
  shipmentDetails:{customerAddressBuildingValue: "ABC",
                   customerAddressBuildingClassValue: "123"}
1:serviceID:'6789',
  shipmentDetails:{customerAddressBuildingValue: "XYZ",
                   customerAddressBuildingClassValue: "567"}
```

But I am getting:

```
0:serviceID:'1234',
  shipmentDetails:{customerAddressBuildingValue: "ABC",
                   customerAddressBuildingClassValue: "123"}
1:serviceID:'6789',
  shipmentDetails:{customerAddressBuildingValue: "ABC",
                   customerAddressBuildingClassValue: "123"}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `if` statement doesn't match object 1? I don't see a `serviceIDX9` property, so it's hard to tell...

Comment: Yes im sure. The reflection of data is happening with only properties of Object within the object of observableArray and not for the properties outside of that object.

Comment: I used $data in data-bind to bind properties from that object but still its failing. Ex:- i am binding data-bind="$data.shipmentDetails.customerAddressBuildingValue"

Comment: But still change in 1st object i.e; "customerAddressBuildingValue" is reflected in 2nd object and vice-versa.